# How can I do a field in react-admin taking as input a icon from IconPicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I want to do a field input where it takes a icon from [IconPicker](https://github.com/fontIconPicker/react-fonticonpicker). How can I do ?

I've tried to do something like that:

*in hardware.js*

```
export const HardwareCreate = (props) => (
    <Create title={<AppTitle />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            ...other normal fields...
            <TextField label="Ícone"/>
            <IconPicker source="icon"/>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

And in iconpicker.js

```
class IconPicker extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             value: 'fipicon-angle-left',
         };
     }
     handleChange = (value) => {
         this.setState({ value });
         console.log(this);
     }
     render() {
         const props = {
             icons: ['fipicon-angle-left', 'fipicon-angle-right', 'fipicon-angle-up', 'fipicon-angle-down'],
             theme: 'bluegrey',
             renderUsing: 'class',
             value: this.state.value,
             onChange: this.handleChange,
             isMulti: false,
    };


    return (
         <FontIconPicker {...props}/>
    );
}

export default IconPicker;
```

Comment: Please share the code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: shared now Marc